# Tablesorter plugin, trigger('search', ...) not triggering

Tags: tablesorter

I am using Table sorter to create a number of pages with tables on them.  I need to add a "Last Week / Month / Year" search function for the dates (which I managed)  but the code is only executing the first time I use one of the buttons.

I made a demo at http://garciaoliver.com/cosas/table/

If you click on the buttons and check your console,  you will see that only the first one you click actually triggers the inner code inside the filter_function

```
filter_functions : {
    '.date-col' : function(e, n) { 
        console.log (e_date > date_start_parsed && e_date < date_end_parsed ? "true" : "false");
        // actual filter code is hidden
    }
}
```

It is however  possible to use the jquery ui date pickers  to change the date as many times as you want (and the code for triggering the search are the same).

I made a jsFiddle so you can check the code (I didn't added all the external resources to actually run the demo).

https://jsfiddle.net/fk7pk3y0/

If you want to download the test files, please go to http://garciaoliver.com/cosas/table/table.tar.gz

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance,
Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search is actually triggering, but the only thing that is being searched is the end date.

Actually, no offense intended, but you were making it way too complicated. I [updated the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fk7pk3y0/3/) by removing the `filter_function` and adding this new function:

```js
function searchTable() {
  var query = [],
    str = '';
  if ( date_search_start && date_search_end ) {
    str = date_search_start + ' - ' + date_search_end;
  } else if ( date_search_start && !date_search_end ) {
    str = '>=' + date_search_start;
  } else if ( !date_search_start && date_search_end ) {
    str = '<=' + date_search_end;
  }
  query[ date_col_id ] = str;
  $table.trigger('search', [ query ]);
}
```

So when only the start is set, it filters dates greater than that set date. If only the end date is set, it filters dates less than that set date. Otherwise, it makes the date into a range.

Before that search will work though, you need to set a "filter-parsed" class on the header so the filter widget knows to only filter parsed values

```html
<th class="date-col filter-parsed">Date</th>
```

I also had to remove the `filter_defaultFilter` setting. And just so you know the `filter_placeholder` option only applies to the filter row, so if you want to add placeholder text to the date picker inputs, you'll need to add a placeholder attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I've tested it and it works like a charm.  I didn't know you could build the query using "<=" etc.  so I did go for the overly complicated solution.    i am still unclear on why I was getting that behaviour  but it doesn't matter now.   Thanks again!